# Spotlight misses first character after Cmd-Space

Tags: macos, keyboard, spotlight

When I call up spotlight by pressing command-space, and then start typing something Spotlight often seems to miss the first letter I type. It doesn't happen every time, only about 1 in 5 times I use it.

i.e. I press Cmd-Space and start to type "Finder" and instead I see "inder" in the text box.

It seems like I am not the only one with this problem https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7296308?tstart=0

Has anyone figured out a solution for this problem?

Comment: [See this post.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226242/spotlight-overrides-first-character/) It's a known bug–the bug report I submitted was marked as duplicate by Apple.

Comment: This is really annoying bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Apple fixes this you can try unchecking 'Allow Spotlight Suggestions in Spotlight and Look up' in System Preferences > Spotlight. It worked for me!